# Stuck with integration of Paypal Express Checkout ( Basic integration checkout.js version 4.0.0)

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I'm trying to integrate Paypal Express Checkout into simple Shopping Cart. There are different ways to do that. Paypal recommends to choose between Basic or Advanced integration and version 4.0 of checkout.js (with REST API). So far so good. 
I created Paypal App in my Paypal account to get credentials and start testing it. 
The test was OK, but there are some misunderstandings here.
Checkout.js send the amount ( 1.00 ) and currency ( EUR ) to the Paypal servers via REST API (along with my credentials). And if the payment is finished OK - callback function onAuthorize is triggered and there are two parameters with response (data and actions). Well, here I call my own AJAX function to write transaction response data in my database. BUT... I get here only PaymentID and PayerID of the paid transaction?!! And if I want to search later into web interface of paypal.com - there is no such thing as PaymentID. There is only TransactionID ??? How to get other transaction  details in the response in onAutorize callback function? How can I get TransactionID here to write down in my database? May be here I have to call Paypal API, or have to implement Paypal IPN (instant payment notification )? BUT how to call IPN API, if I don't have TransactionID :)

```
<div style="width: 906px; text-align: right; height: 100px; 
     margin-top: 50px;">
<div id="paypal-button"></div> 
</div>

<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>

<script>
    paypal.Button.render({

        env: 'production', // Optional: specify 'sandbox' environment

        style: {
            size: 'medium',
            shape: 'rect'
        },

        client: {
            sandbox:    'xxx-my-credentials-xxx',
            production: 'xxx-my-credentials-xxx'
        },

        payment: function() {

            var env    = this.props.env;
            var client = this.props.client;

            return paypal.rest.payment.create(env, client, {
                transactions: [
                    {
                        amount: { total: '1.00', currency: 'EUR' }
                    }
                ]
            });
        },

        commit: true, // Optional: show a 'Pay Now' button in the checkout flow

        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

            // Optional: display a confirmation page here   
            var EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL = 'payment-process.php'; 

paypal.request.post(EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL, { paymentID: data.paymentID, payerID: data.payerID, transactionID: data.transactionID, data: data }) .then(function(data) { }) .catch(function(err) { }); 


            return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
                // Show a success page to the buyer
            });
        }

    }, '#paypal-button');
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

To read the information from the transaction you need to call and save data JSON in database

```
    return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
                actions.payment.get().then(function(data) {
                 if(data.state === 'approved'){
                   console.log(data);  
                   var transactionId = data.id;
                   alert("Transaction ID: "+ transactionId + " \n State: " +data.state);
                 }else{
                  console.log(data);
                 }
               });
          });
```

Comment: But is data.id the transaction or payment id ? i found these to be different

Comment: data.id is transaction id.

Comment: Is it **data.state** or **data.status**?

Comment: it's data.state. it state of payment.